# WinJS 2.0 NavBar selection after Right/Left keyboard clicks

Tags: css, winjs, navbar

guys, 
I have a problem with WinJS 2.0 navBar control.

If I open navBar on the page and tap right *keyboard* key - it selects the first navBar command and add Black border to it. And so on.

Could you please help me, how **not** to add a border to navBar command?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you use the document inspector in VS to determine what the CSS is that's causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding following rule in your css:

```
.win-navbarcommand-button.win-keyboard:focus,
.win-navbarcommand-splitbutton.win-keyboard:focus {
   outline: none;
}
```

It will preventing showing outline when navigating nav bar using keyboard, although honestly I think you should think twice about it as it's good to show user who uses keyboard which item is currently selected/focused in nav bar.